# Speeding up program video stream

Tags: python, performance, sockets, opencv, video

I'm writing a server-client video stream, The server gets the video captured by the clients camera.

My program is working, but my problem is that the video is very slow, with 9+- sec of delay, I wonder how I can speed it up to get better performance?

This is my server:

```
import socket
import cv2
import pickle
import struct

HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 8765

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

s.bind((HOST, PORT))
print 'Socket bind complete'
s.listen(1)
print 'Socket now listening'

conn, addr = s.accept()
data = ""
payload_size = struct.calcsize("L")
while True:
    while len(data) < payload_size:
        data += conn.recv(131072)
    packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]

    data = data[payload_size:]
    msg_size = struct.unpack("L", packed_msg_size)[0]

    while len(data) < msg_size:
        data += conn.recv(131072)
    frame_data = data[:msg_size]
    data = data[msg_size:]

    frame=pickle.loads(frame_data)
    #print frame.size
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

And this is my client:

```
import cv2
import socket
import pickle
import struct

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 8765))

while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    data = pickle.dumps(frame)
    clientsocket.sendall(struct.pack("L", len(data)) + data)
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: struct.pack converts your data into a string, right? This string is much larger than your frame data. You should send the raw data.

Comment: How would i know i got the all frame? my pack makes sure all my data arrives

Comment: I ran the server code on python3 and it gave me the following error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 22, in <module>
    data += conn.recv(131072)
TypeError: must be str, not bytes" . And the client code gave me the following error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 13, in <module>
    clientsocket.sendall(struct.pack("L", len(data)) + data)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe"